# Sockets can't send data

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

**Code**

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
port=4446
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(1)

print("Listening for connections...")

q,addr = s.accept()

data = input("Type something in")
q.send(data)
s.close
```

**Error**

```
TypeError:'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

So I know that there are hundreds of questions on here about this error but I still cant think up a solution, can one of you guys help me out? :(

Comment: @Wooble: That's one for the http://sopython.com frequent questions list..

Comment: @Wooble I couldnt find my answer using any of the other questions so I made my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, strings are *Unicode* values, but sockets can only take encoded bytes.

Encode your data first:

```
q.send(data.encode('utf8'))
```

I picked UTF-8 here as the codec to use, but you need to consciously pick a encoding suitable to your specific application.

Comment: Should I make a new question about a client problem I just got, or post it here?

Comment: I'd make that a new question.

Comment: I have to wait 20 minutes between questions :( IMM NOT A ROBOAT

Comment: @user3241744: pick your questions carefully, make sure we have a clear example of what is going wrong, and the 20 minutes will fly by. The rate limit is not there just for robots, btw.

Comment: Haha, 20 minutes already went by that was fast.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are Unicode objects in python 3. You need to encode it to a byte string before sending.

```
Data.encode("ASCII")
```